# Has_many through association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

In my `Node` model I have the association below, where two `nodes` are linked in the `Link` model:

```
has_many :first_links, class_name:  "Link",
                       foreign_key: "first_node_id"
has_many :second_links, class_name:  "Link",
                        foreign_key: "second_node_id"
belongs_to :organization
```

I basically just want to have all the links associated to a node, irrespective whether the node is `first_node` or `second_node`. Therefore I also have the method below in the `Node` model:

```
def links
  first_links + second_links
end
```

If I now try `Node.first.links` in the console, then it works and I get a list of all links for that node, irrespective if that node is first or second node of the link. So this relationship seems to be working.

In the `Organization` model I have:

```
has_many :nodes
has_many :links, through: :nodes, source: :links
```

However, `Organization.first.links` in the console generates the error:

> Could not find the source association(s) "link" or :links in model
>   Node.

What am I doing wrong for the `through` association?

---

**Update:** I understand now that I need a custom method to collect all the `links` for an `organization`. The following made most sense to me (added to the `Organization` model):

```
has_many :nodes
def links
  nodes.each do |node|
    self.links ||= []            #Create the array if it doesn't exist yet.
    links << node.links.collect  #Add all the links to the array.
  end
end
```

If I try `Organization.first.links` in the console, this produces the error below. Any idea what the method should look like?

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:282:in `blame_file!': can't modify frozen fatal (RuntimeError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm..

You can only call `organization.nodes` and not `organization.links`, since that is just a method in the `Node` class.

What you can try, however, is to create a similar method (which will be an instance method) in the `Organization` class, to return all links for all nodes belonging to the instance of `Organization` on which the newly created method is called.

Eg:

```
def links
  self.nodes.joins(:first_links) + self.nodes.joins(:second_links)
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to use the association in an `active model serializer`. I'm not sure is a custom method would also work in the serializer...!?

Comment: A custom method seems possible:https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/serializers.md#overriding-association-methods. I'll try and will update my Original post with the method.